# Angularjs initializing value in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have folllowing html input that takes value and calls  in controller function

```
  <input type="text" name="netid" ng-model="c.netid"  ng-blur="blurCallback(c.netid)"/>
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="c.name" ng-init="c.name={{testing}}" />
```

Controller function

```
   $scope.blurCallback = function (netId) {
           var netName=netId;
               AppRepository.checkPerson.get(netName, function (data) {
                   $scope.testing=data.name      
            })
        }
```

Code is working fine, except $scope.testing does not update the value in the DOM at ng-model=c.name. Please let me know how it is done right way in Angularjs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the angularJs documentation:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Source: [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Instead I would set the value of your ng-model in the blur function like this:

```
    $scope.blurCallback = function (netId) {
        var netName=netId;
        AppRepository.checkPerson.get(netName, function (data) {
               $scope.c.name = data.name;      
        });
    }
```

Comment: when I use $scope.c.name it gives me error for $scope.c undefined. But when I remove c and just do $scope.name it will display the name but I need to have ng-model="c.name" to use when submitting all the values. Any ideas?

Comment: Try initialize $scope.c to an empty object likes this: $scope.c = {} in the beginning of the controller.